# Conditional search in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am trying to select values from a dataframe of precipitation and stream flow.   I need to select flow data following a period of 5 days of low precipitation (say 2mm), and decide if the flow numbers are decreasing day by day.   Can anyone help me with the how to code this?  The data frame looks as below, but for several decades:

| Date | Flow(mm) | Precip(mm) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/59 | 2.588 | 2.54 |
| 01/01/1960 | 1.861 | 0.00 |
| 01/02/1960 | 1.578 | 0.76 |

Answer (score 1):

Function for conditional search for selecting data flow following a period of n days of low precipitation (threshold) decreasing day by day assuming the "Date" column is the index:

```
def conditional_search(dataframe, threshold = 0.2, n = 5):
    searched = []
    
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index() # resets index --> 0, 1, 2...
    
    for index in dataframe.index: # iterates through the rows
        consecutives = dataframe.loc[index:index + n - 1] # next n values

        if (consecutives.shape[0] == n) & (consecutives['Precip(mm)'] < threshold).values.all(): # checks values less than threshold
            consecutives_decreasing = (consecutives['Precip(mm)'] - consecutives['Precip(mm)'].shift(-1)) > 0 # substracts precipitation column shifted up one from precipitation column and checks if they are positive

            if consecutives_decreasing.loc[consecutives_decreasing == True].shape[0] == n - 1: # checks if the number of positive subtractions are equal to n - 1
                searched.append(consecutives.set_index("Date"))
                
    return searched # returns a list of dataframes containing the searched values following the condition
```

Example:

Input:

```
            Flow(mm)  Precip(mm)
Date                            
12/31/1959     2.588        2.54
01/01/1960     1.861        2.53
01/02/1960     1.578        2.52
01/03/1960     1.578        2.51
01/04/1960     1.578        2.50
01/04/1960     1.578        3.89
```

Output:

```
[            Flow(mm)  Precip(mm)
 Date                            
 12/31/1959     2.588        2.54
 01/01/1960     1.861        2.53
 01/02/1960     1.578        2.52
 01/03/1960     1.578        2.51
 01/04/1960     1.578        2.50]
```